# Generating Pmml code for data calculations in R

Tags: r, pmml

I am generating some derived fields from a data set given to me. Below is an example of one such derived field. I am calculating age from birth date. Is there a way to generate pmml code for such calculations.

age <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) - as.numeric(format(as.Date(birth_date, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y"))

Comment: The `pmml` package supports export to PMML.  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [PMML built-in functions](http://www.dmg.org/v4-2-1/BuiltinFunctions.html) `dateDaysSinceYear` and `dateSecondsSinceYear`.